# Should I thread if database query is under 100ms

Tags: java, android, database, performance, android-asynctask

I am writing an app that requires to write and retrieve data from a database. I am wondering if I should run a the query in a thread/Asynctask because it takes less than 100ms, in fact, one call usually takes about 30-70ms (and among parsing the cursor included). This call only retrieves one row from each of the 2 (different) databases. If I add an asynctask, the time goes to 120-170ms (I guess from the overhead). Is it worth (or better practice) to use a thread/asynctask for such small durations?

Comment: if you are dependent on the result of the query to proceed further it wont be of any use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you want to run a database query in a separate thread is because the database is an external dependency that you can't fully control (in production code).  What that means is that even though your query *usually* runs happily in 100ms, there will be times when problems arise and you need a way to handle situations in which the query doesn't even return at all.  By encapsulating this functionality within a separate thread, you have much better control over what happens when things go wrong.  For example, if there is a problem with the database, it is possible to set a timeout period after which your code can assume an error took place and retry or kill the hung query thread without causing your whole program to be blocked and require a restart to continue.  There are several techniques for doing what I just said, so I cannot be too specific because I don't know what your exact situation involves and what the trade-offs might be.  I think the overall point I am trying to make is that there is a big difference between code we write to try something out and code we write to put into production.

Writing dependable multi-threaded code is hard work.  I recommend you take the time to read and understand Goetz's book **Java Concurrency in Practice** to help you solve your concurrency problems.

Comment: Thanks, I had a similar thought. Now I am sure that threading is the correct way to do things.

Answer (score 2):

It would be good practice to run queries on AsyncTask. In the beginning everything runs smooth, but when the database get larger, the query might take above second. Then you should be able to show wait dialog for the user, not just freeze the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that is going to consume time should not be done on Main UI thread. It is always recommended to perform DB operations in Async Tasks. One of the prime reasons being your metric of time take for the operation will vary depending on the phone configuration and other parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think multi threading is necessary when you need to achieve parallelism. If your code runs in series, i mean one after one from start to end then you don't need threading.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dependent on result of the query output then you would in any case have to wait for the result.

For better performance with database consider using **Prepared Statement Caching** (Use parameterized  Prepared statements)

That should increase some performance.